# if multiple random numbers are all equal return true

Tags: php, random, operand

Im working on some random generator, and it's something like roll a dices, if all dices are returning same numbers than you won a game if not than you try again.

To get six dices i used mt_rand function and for every dice separately, so i have this:

```
$first = mt_rand(1,6);
$second = mt_rand(1,6);
$third = mt_rand(1,6);
$fourth = mt_rand(1,6);
$fifth = mt_rand(1,6);
$sixth = mt_rand(1,6);
```

But i don't know how to return if operand for multiple random generated numbers.

If i would use like 2 dices i would just use

```
if ( $first === $second )
```

that would return true if first and second dices, both have returned number 2

But how do i use it if i want to echo true if all 6 dices to return number 2 ?

Edit:
number 2 is just an example if i would need only number 2 i know how to do it with array and variable but point is that i need only all numbers to match, it doesn't matter which ones from 1 to 6. And first answer actually works but let's see if it's possible to do with array.

Comment: `$first === $second && $second === $third && $third === $fourth ...` etc

Comment: Learning to use arrays will make this easier, then you can use functions like [array_count_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays to make your life easier (e.g. `$dices` with indices from 0 to 5)

Just put it in a loop and check at every iteration. If one dice isn't 2, `$allDicesSameNumber` wil be false.

```
$number = mt_rand(1, 6);
$allDicesSameNumber = true;
for ($i = 1; $i < 6 /* dices */; $i++) {
    $dices[$i] = mt_rand(1, 6);

    if ($dices[$i] !== $number)
        $allDicesSameNumber = false;
}
```

Comment: but this is when it's locked to number 2 i need to match all 6 dices with same number it doesn't matter which one.

Comment: Sorry for stupidity but is this gonna decrease chances of winning, it's like im rolling 7 dices now, first we generate 1 random number in $number than we need to match it with 6 other random generated numbers?

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević No, you just roll 6 dices. Because I changed `$i` to start at 1 instead of zero. Look at [the diff](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18752729/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

```
$diceCount = 6;
$diceArray = array();
for($i=1; $i<=$diceCount; $i++) {
    $diceArray[] = mt_rand(1,6);
}
if (count(array_count_values($diceArray) == 1) {
    echo 'All the dice have the same number';
}
```

Comment: I get an error Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted on line where $diceArray[] = mt_rand(1,6);

Comment: mea culpa.... change `for($i=1; $i=$diceCount; $i++) {` to `for($i=1; $i<=$diceCount; $i++) {`